# Query JOIN And Count ON Postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I use Postgresql. I have a & b table like this

```
a_table
+--------+---------------+
|   id   |   free_value  |
+--------+---------------+
|   1    |      3        |
|   2    |      2        |
|   3    |      1        |
|   4    |      3        |
|   5    |      2        |
|   6    |      8        |
|   7    |      4        |
+--------+---------------+

b_table
+--------+---------------+
|   id   |   a_table_id  |
+--------+---------------+
|   1    |      2        |
|   2    |      2        |
|   3    |      6        |
|   4    |      5        |
|   5    |      3        |
|   6    |      3        |
+--------+---------------+
```

Can I write query for count free_value on b_table and desc to count like this ?

```
count_free_value_table
+----------------+-----------+
|   free_value   |   count   |
+----------------+-----------+
|       2        |     3     |
|       1        |     2     |
|       8        |     1     |
|       3        |     0     |
|       4        |     0     |
+----------------+-----------+
```

I try with `SELECT free_value, count(free_value) from a_table LEFT JOIN b_table ON a_table.id = b_table.a_table_id` But It is not work.

Thank you for any help. I am be silly for this.

Comment: `SELECT free_value, count(*) from a_table LEFT JOIN b_table ON a_table.id = b_table.a_table_id group by free_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `COUNT(b_table.id)` instead; `COUNT` counts all non-null values encountered, which is why (I am guessing) you were getting 1 for the unmatched `free_values`; because the unmatched values still have their own values in their rows.

Edit: Also, are's comment and Alim's answer are also correct in that you need to `group by free_value`. *Otherwise, you'll get total rows of the JOIN, and an effectively randomly chosen `free_value`.*

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT free_value, count(free_value)
from a_table LEFT JOIN b_table ON a_table.id = b_table.a_table_id 
group by free_value
```

Comment: counting `free_value` will result in 1's for values with no references.

Comment: I change count(free_value) to count(b_table.id) and it work right thank for @Uueerdo too. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT free_value, count( b_table.id ) count
FROM a_table
LEFT JOIN b_table ON a_table.id = b_table.a_table_id
GROUP BY free_value
ORDER BY count DESC
```

try this query.